# External XML for culture-specific text / Translation mapping

Tags: xml, performance, xpath, xslt-1.0

We are building a system that gets XML data from a database, uses XSLT to transform it to XHTML and at the same time use an external XML file to retrieve culture-specific labels (*translations for our labels*).

**Short Question**
Does the translation/culture-specific system seem logical ? Efficient ?

Any alternative concepts are welcome (*in this specific context*)

---

**Detailed Question**

**XML data**

```
<page id="55" objecttype="ChristianOrthodoxMonument">
 <field name="uniquename">some unique name here</field>
        .. multiple field elements here ..
</page>
```

**XML culture-labels**

```
<ChristianOrthodoxMonument>
 <uniquename culture-1="Ονομασία" culture-2="Unique name" />
 <birthdate culture-1="Ημ/νία γέννησης" culture-2="Date of birth" />
</ChristianOrthodoxMonument>
```

now in XSLT i pass the `cultureid` parameter to be used for the mapping to the labels.

**XSLT** (*example snippet*)

```
<xsl:param name="cultureid" select="1" />
<xsl:variable name="objecttype" select="/page/@objecttype" />
```

and to map to the external file which is included with

```
<xsl:variable name="culture" select="document('cultural-labels.xml')" />
```

i created a pseudo dynamic xpath

```
<xsl:template name="translate">
 <xsl:variable name="nodename" select="@name" />
 <xsl:value-of select="$culture/*[name()=$objecttype]/*[name()=$nodename]/@*[name()=concat('culture-',$cultureid)]" />
</xsl:template>
```

which i call whenever i want to get the label for a field.

**Question A :** is this xpath efficient or overkill ? overcomplicated ?
**Question B :** does this model seem right or am  i missing something vital that will prove to be an obstacle in the future ?
**Question C :** Is there any theory/example on similar mapping techniques to external XML files ?

---

**2nd Update** *with composite key usage*

**key**

```
<xsl:key name="find-node" match="*" use="concat(name(..),'!',name())"  />
```

**lookup**

```
<xsl:template name="lookup-label">
<xsl:param name="objecttype" />
<xsl:variable name="nodename" select="@name" />
<xsl:for-each select="$culture">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('find-node',concat($objecttype,'!',$nodename))/@*[name()=$culturefield]" />
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

is this an improvement ?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my reply for concrete answers to all your questions and pointers to examples of efficient implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Short Question** Does the translation/culture-specific system
>   seem logical ?

**Yes**.

> Efficient ?

**It *can* be efficient -- not exactly your implementation.**

> i created a pseudo dynamic xpath
>
> ```
> <xsl:template name="translate"> 
>  <xsl:variable name="nodename" select="@name" /> 
>  <xsl:value-of select=
>   "$culture/*[name()=$objecttype]
>                /*[name()=$nodename]
>                     /@*[name()=concat('culture-',$cultureid)]"
> ```
>
> />
>
> which i call whenever i want to get
>   the label for a field.
>
> **Question A** : is this xpath efficient or overkill ?

No, it isn't efficient, because the whole XML document will be traversed many times to find specific objecttype nodes.

> overcomplicated ?

No.

> **Question B** : does this model seem right or am i missing something vital
>   that will prove to be an obstacle in
>   the future ?

The model is generally OK.

> **Question C** : Is there any theory/example on similar mapping
>   techniques to external XML files ?

**There are [many examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852578/xslt-external-lookup-table-correct-usage-key-function) of efficient lookup based on keys -- even at SO. Also see [this one](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4995.html#d6579e97)**.

Comment: @Dimitre, thanks for the pointers and links. I think I am understanding the key concept, but seeing that most uses are with attribute searches while mine is based on nodenames (*2 levels deep*). Is [this approach](http://pastebin.com/yA1ryLaQ) an improvement?

Comment: @Gaby: The key value is just a string. It could be built from attribute, node names... any other strings or concatenations.

Comment: @Gaby: There is no requirement that the key should come from an attribute. You can see a lot of examples of using keys here: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4852.html

Comment: @Dimitre, i had it working with nodes, but wanted a comment on the actual implementation (*the link in my comment*). I have updated my answer with my *solution*. If you care to comment on that i would appreciate it very much.

Comment: @Gaby: I wouldn't use two keys. I would use one key whose index is the concatenation of `$objecttype` and `$nodename`.

Comment: @Gaby: If you provide a full (but as short as possible) example: XML documents, XSLT stylesheet and the result you get -- then I could try to improve it. Right now I don't have enough information,

Comment: @Dimitre, my code can be found at http://gaby.pastebin.com/archive_subdomain.php?p=1 Thanks for all the help and for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another pure XSLT approach: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/jxslt/ch08_06.htm

Another alternative might be to call java functions from xslt (look [here](http://www.edankert.com/transforms/xslt.invoke-java.html)) or C# (look [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_22792010.html). This has multiple advantages

- Leverage the functionaity/tools offered by these languages
- Same bundles/translation files can be shared

Comment: +1, thanks for the links. Nice concept in the first one, but i prefer to keep it as agnostic as possible, so i avoid using variables directly, that get overridden. My structure is a bit more deep.